# Merging two sorted lists into one sorted list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, mergesort

I have 2 sorted lists.
I want to merge them to have one sorted list.

What I tried:

```
def mergeSortedArrays_improved(arr1=[], arr2=[]):
    mergedArray = []
    arr1_item = arr1[0]
    arr2_item = arr2[0]
    i = 1
    j = 1
    while(arr1_item or arr2_item):
        print(arr1_item, arr2_item)
        if(arr1_item < arr2_item):
            mergedArray.append(arr1_item)
            print(f"appended {arr1_item} to list")
            arr1_item = arr1[i]
            i+=1
        else:
            mergedArray.append(arr2_item)
            print(f"appended {arr2_item} to list")
            arr2_item = arr2[j]
            j+=1
        
    return mergedArray

z = mergeSortedArrays_improved([0,3,4,31],[4,6,30])
print(z)
```

The output at console mentions:

```
0 4
appended 0 to list
3 4
appended 3 to list
4 4
appended 4 to list
4 6
appended 4 to list
31 6
appended 6 to list
31 30
appended 30 to list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 40, in <module>
    z = mergeSortedArrays_improved([0,3,4,31],[4,6,30])
  File "main.py", line 35, in mergeSortedArrays_improved
    arr2_item = arr2[j]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

In Java, I could have done something like:

```
if((!arr2_item) || (arr1_item < arr2_item)) # would have solved this issue
```

In Python, how to fix this issue:
I tried using j >= len(arr2), but it dint work. Can you please help me with the issue

Comment: Do not set [] as default in method arguments : https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
def mergeSortedArrays_improved(arr1, arr2):
    mergedArray = []
    
    for i in arr1:
        mergedArray.append(i)
    for i in arr2:
        mergedArray.append(i)
    
    for i in range(len(mergedArray)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(mergedArray)):
            if mergedArray[i] > mergedArray[j]:
                temp = mergedArray[i]
                mergedArray[i] = mergedArray[j]
                mergedArray[j] = temp
    return mergedArray

print(mergeSortedArrays_improved([0,3,4,31],[4,6,30]))
```

Comment: Thanks Nitin, but the goal is not to use the inbuilt function. Thanks

Comment: Super Nitin. I came up with this same code you wrote. It has a complexity of O(n^2). In order to improve it, I have created "mergeSortedArrays_improved" version. What do you think, can we reduce complexity to O(n)?

Comment: No, I think, it can be as low as `0(nlogn)` with the sort function. Even with bubble sort, the time complexity in worst case is `0(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mergeSortedArrays_improved(arr1=[], arr2=[]):
    mergedArray = []
    arr1_item = arr1[0]
    arr2_item = arr2[0]
    i = j = flag = 0
    while not (i >=len(arr1) or (j>=len(arr2))):
        print(arr1_item, arr2_item)
        if(arr1[i] < arr2[j]):
            mergedArray.append(arr1[i])
            print(f"appended {arr1[i]} to list")
            i+=1
        else:
            mergedArray.append(arr2[j])
            print(f"appended {arr2[j]} to list")
            j+=1
        
        if i == len(arr1):
            flag = 1

    if flag==1: 
        # means elements in first array were over, simply append elements from second array to new mergedArray
        for idx in range(j, len(arr2)):
            mergedArray.append(arr2[idx])
    else:
        for idx in range(i, len(arr1)):
            mergedArray.append(arr1[idx])

    return mergedArray

z = mergeSortedArrays_improved([0,3,4,31,85],[4,6,30,65,77,99])
print(z)
```